# Missing gaps between menu items in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

I have noticed that gaps between different options in Notepad++ menu have disappeared.

Help me please to find out what's wrong.

Here are screens:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Notepad++ are you using? Press `F1` when in Notepad++ to see the version number. Wonder if an uninstall, reinstall latest version would do it. There may be an XML file controlling this in the installation directory or something else that's corrupt or not right causing which an uninstall may resolve (or upgrade to latest version). Might also be worth a computer reboot before you try that in case something in memory is corrupt, etc. causing it. A reboot should refresh all volatile for certain.

Comment: does it happen only with notepad++ or all other apps that use Windows native menu?

Comment: Is it only in dark mode this happens?

Comment: So, it happens only in dark mode.  But using only light theme isn't a great solution for me.

Comment: [Thread link found at Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21565/dark-mode-problem). Some hints for you but solution missing.

Comment: What's the Notepad++ version? Did you try updaitng/reinstalling? Did you try a different dark theme?

Comment: Yes, I have tried reinstalling/updating the notepad++, no results. It happens This happens with most dark themes

Comment: Please edit the question whenever you add new info. What's the exact system + version? Anyways, I can't reproduce this personally on Win 10, it's fine with dark themes that I have including the default one, so can't really help further.

Comment: I think I have found a reason why it's happening. I use custom theme for windows, so that is the reason. I have checked it on default system theme and it is fine